# MySQL combine columns before matching it with LIKE

Tags: mysql, database, sql-like

I have two columns in my database that I want to combine before matching them using `LIKE` statement.

My table:

```
|---------------------------------|
|   ID     |   PREFIX  |  SUFFIX  |
|---------------------------------|
|   1      |     31    |   523    |
|---------------------------------|
|   2      |     62    |   364    |
|---------------------------------|
```

I want to be able to supply `315` and `ID 1` would be returned. Is there any easy way of doing it? At the moment I am splitting search string and matching separate columns.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT(PREFIX, SUFFIX) LIKE '%315%'
```

Comment: Thanks! It's easy once you know it =]